# Converting Large XML file to java object?

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I have large size xml file which can vary from 500 mb to 2 gb on which i want to do validations
like total number of custom tags and other validations. My question is there a good way so that i marshal the 
complete xml file to java object without OutOfMemory exception? I don't think its possible as i have RAM of 2 GB
and ram size of 1536 MB. But then, What's the alternative?

Should i split the xml into smaller xml files using STAX/SAX and then have separate objects ? Then count the customer
elements in each java object. Store it as instance variable then repeat it for further xml. Aggregate all the customer 
counts. If yes , how will i know decomposed xmls are part of single xml. Probably i need to introduce the some correlation Id 
in the file name so that i can know separate xml nodes are the part of single XML node?

Comment: will it be possible for you to have an in memory database setup? If yes, you can read the xml through stax/sax and store the data into db tables. Then you can do the validations using sql queries. And you H2 will run in a separate jvm, so memory shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well for parsing the xml of the sizes that you have mentioned[upto 2GB] you dont have to load all of it in RAM. You can use SAX parser for parsing it. [Here](http://andreas.haufler.info/2012/01/conveniently-processing-large-xml-files.html) i found an interesting way of doing so

```
XMLReader r = new XMLReader();

   r.addHandler("node", new NodeHandler() {

     @Override
     public void process(StructuredNode node) {
       System.out.println(node.queryString("name"));
       System.out.println(node.queryValue("price").asDouble(0d));
     }
   });

   r.parse(new FileInputStream("src/examples/test.xml"));
```

Basicaly it is a mixture of SAX and DOM. It creates do for the element where you have some data to be processed. Code for this is under MIT licence and can be found [here](https://github.com/andyHa/scireumOpen)

If above is not feasible for you that i would suggest that you should go for plain StAX parser [Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/stax.html) is a good tutorial to start with

Answer (score 1):

[SAX (Simple API for XML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) will help you here.

> Unlike the DOM parser, the SAX parser does not create an in-memory
>   representation of the XML document and so is faster and uses less
>   memory. Instead, the SAX parser informs clients of the XML document
>   structure by invoking callbacks, that is, by invoking methods on a
>   `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` instance provided to the parser.

Here is an example implementation:

```
SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
DefaultHandler handler = new MyHandler();
parser.parse("file.xml", handler);
```

Where in `MyHandler` you define the actions to be taken when events like start/end of document/element are generated.

```
class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
    }

    // To take specific actions for each chunk of character data (such as
    // adding the data to a node or buffer, or printing it to a file).
    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
    }

}
```